# rows.splice() always delete last row when having react-select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-select

I have a html table, inside which each rows is having react-select element and button to remove the same row. I pass the selected row index and trying to remove the same row. when removing the last row , its working fine however when I click on any of the top rows example with values "test1" given in below picture, its removing the last row with select value as "test4" , I have passed the index values correctly still its removing the last row.

[image: display table]

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

function App(props) {
  //const options = compliments;
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    rows: [
      {
        config: ""
      }
    ]
  });
  const [configOpts, setConfigOpts] = useState([]);

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    const newRow = {
      config: ""
    };
    setState({
      ...state,
      rows: [...state.rows, newRow]
    });
  };

  const handleRemoveRow = (idx) => () => {
    const rows = [...state.rows];
    rows.splice(idx, 1);
    setState({
      ...state,
      rows
    });
  };

  const handleConfigChange = (index) => (selectedOption) => {
    console.log("SelectedOption: " + selectedOption.label);
    const rows = [...state.rows];
    rows[index] = {
      ...rows[index],
      ["config"]: selectedOption.label
    };
    setState({
      ...state,
      rows
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setConfigOpts([
      { label: "Test1", value: "Test1" },
      { label: "Test2", value: "Test2" },
      { label: "Test3", value: "Test3" },
      { label: "Test4", value: "Test4" }
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        {state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
          <tr key={idx}>
            <td>
              <Select options={configOpts} onChange={handleConfigChange(idx)} />
            </td>
            <td>
              <button onClick={handleRemoveRow(idx)}>Remove</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleAddRow}>Add</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-sara-68x1zh?file=/src/App.js:0-1602)

Answer (score 0):

The following code performs as expected without any issues.

In this following updated code, **each row has a unique id generated by incrementing** the `id variable`. The `handleRemoveRow` function now **filters the rows** array **based on the id**.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

function App(props) {
  //const options = compliments;
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    rows: [
      {
        rowId: 0,
        config: ""
      }
    ],
    id: 1
  });
  const [configOpts, setConfigOpts] = useState([]);

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    const newRow = {
      rowId: state.id,
      config: ""
    };
    setState({
      ...state,
      rows: [...state.rows, newRow],
      id: state.id + 1
    });
  };

  const handleRemoveRow = (idx) => () => {
    const rows = state.rows.filter((FilterdRow) => FilterdRow.rowId !== idx);
    console.log("rows", rows);

    setState({
      ...state,
      rows
    });
  };

  const handleConfigChange = (index) => (selectedOption) => {
    console.log("SelectedOption: " + selectedOption.label);
    const rows = state.rows.map((row) => {
      if (row.id === index) {
        return {
          ...row,
          ["config"]: selectedOption.label
        };
      }
      return row;
    });
    setState({
      ...state,
      rows
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setConfigOpts([
      { label: "Test1", value: "Test1" },
      { label: "Test2", value: "Test2" },
      { label: "Test3", value: "Test3" },
      { label: "Test4", value: "Test4" }
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        {state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
          <tr key={item.rowId}>
            <td>
              <Select
                options={configOpts}
                onChange={handleConfigChange(item.rowId)}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <button onClick={handleRemoveRow(item.rowId)}>Remove</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleAddRow}>Add</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I can not use id in the state, its small part of complete code I have provided, also key has to be the index one only.